# how to open the miniscript designer?

Tags: bitcoin-core, miniscript

I've read Bitcoin Core 24 brings a miniscript visual programmer. Had a look, didn't find it.

Is that true?
How to check it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such feature included in Bitcoin Core.

What is included in Bitcoin Core v24.0rc1 is the ability to use miniscript in imported output script descriptors, with the restriction that it is watch only (signing support will likely be for 25.0).

There are other tools out there, developed independently, that let you design scripts using miniscript-based tooling. Including:

- https://bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript (disclaimer: my own site), which lets you compile policies to miniscript.
- https://min.sc, the minsc language, a layer on top of the Miniscript policy language.
- https://miniscript.fun, a site to play around with Miniscript in a visual way

Comment: Were descriptors invented for being able to comfortably systematize complex spending policies? Or were descriptors themselves invented before systematized complex spending policies could be thought of on descriptors?

Comment: Both, I guess. Descriptors were originally designed to be able to generalize key/address derivation to future script versions, as well as multisig. Once that existed, the miniscript research showed that this approach could reasonably be extended to far more complex script constructions than originally aimed for.

Answer (score 1):

No, Bitcoin Core has no graphical interface for miniscript. However, the [24.0 Release Candidate Testing Guide](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/bitcoin-devwiki/wiki/24.0-Release-Candidate-Testing-Guide) mentions [miniscript.fun](https://miniscript.fun), a graphical playground for miniscript, which is likely what you're referring to.